# Using CDI in java application

Tags: cdi

I'm writing Java SE application that uses CDI. 
I have bean definition:

```
public class BeanA {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("INIT");
    }

    public void receive(@Observes String test) {
        System.out.println("received: " + test);
    }
}
```

Requirements: 
- I need to have many instances of `BeanA` in application
- I'd like to use Event CDI mechanism to communicate with that objects

When I use `@Dependent` scope, then `@PostConstruct` of `BeanA` is called everytime a new message is received. When I use `@Singleton` or `@ApplicationScope` then I can't have many objects of `BeanA` type.

What is solution to my problem?

Comment: Is there a cap to the number of these `BeanA` instances you're creating?  Are they associated to sessions?

Comment: There is no limit of BeanA instances. There is no session as well.

Comment: How do `BeanA` instances get created then? What triggers them?  It obviously can't be this event then.

Comment: What is the problem with `@Dependent`? You create as many objects as you have messages, what do you need else?

Comment: @JohnAment in other bean there is Inject private void BeanA bean;

Comment: Right, but each injection point is a brand new bean.  They go away when the object they get injected to is destroyed.